# How to reuse Custom UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionviewcell

I have used following code

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(78, 86);
[layout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:4.5f];
[layout setMinimumLineSpacing:4.5f];
self.collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100) collectionViewLayout:layout];
 [self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
[self.collectionView setDelegate:self];
[self.collectionView setTag:1];
[self.collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

How to reuse the cell identifier in UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: the issue comes in only ios 7 or all the versions

Comment: did face any warning or runtime error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this

```
static NSString *kCellReuseIdentifier = @"cell"; 

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```